# Redirect website using JavaScript for only mobile users with option to return to original site

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like redirect my website for only mobile users. I can figure out JavaScript code to redirect. But, my main problem is: I want to give users another option to get back to the current website. How can I do this using JavaScript?

This code forces users with small width screens to go to the mobile version of the website.

```js
var w = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth ||
        document.body.clientWidth;

if(w < 600) {
    window.location.assign("http://example.com/mobile");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use a cookie or local storage to keep the user choice and take it in account with the page width to trigger the redirection or not.

More precisely (untested code):

```
/* http://example.com/desktop */

var w = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth ||
    document.body.clientWidth,
    forced_desktop = localStorage.getItem('desktop') ? true : false;

if( ! forced_desktop && w < 600) {
    window.location.assign("http://example.com/mobile");
}
```

Then on mobile dedicated pages, use something like:

```
<script>
/* http://example.com/mobile */

function back_to_desktop() {
    localStorage.setItem('desktop', 'forced');
    window.location.assign("http://example.com/desktop");
}
</script>
<a href='#' onclick='back_to_desktop();'>Desktop version</a>
```

local storage is used here, but you could do the same with a cookie or even via url parameters.

Comment: can you please explain further?

Comment: given some more explanations